# Transparent foreground

Tags: jquery, css, transparency

I would like to add a semi-transparent uniform layer as a foreground for a `div` element. What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use this CSS...

```
div.parent {
   position: relative;
}

/* this div is a descendent of the div above */
div.child {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   opacity: .6;
   background: #fff;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dppJw/).

If you want mouse events to go *through* this cover, add [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/pointer-events) to the `div.child`.

You tagged it jQuery, so to add this *child* element via jQuery...

```
$('div.parent').append('<div class="child" />');
```

Comment: `filter: alpha(opacity=60)` for I.E. 8 & below.

Comment: This is how I'd do it, too; be aware that you have to jump through a few hoops if you need things like text selection or if you want to capture events.

Comment: Updated fiddle with mouse capture as per alex' update: http://jsfiddle.net/dppJw/1/ Awesome! I didn't know it would be that easy, thanks for the update.