# Foreground on window except for specified element

Tags: jquery

I have found how to make a semi-transparent foreground on a set of HTML elements [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642030/transparent-foreground).

However, I would like to put a foreground on the whole document *except* a specified element. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what it sounds like what you want to do is add an overlay to the whole document except for one element. You can do this by adding the overlay to the whole document with a z-index of say 50, and giving your specified element a higher z-index so it displays above the overlay.

Is that basically what you wanted?

EDIT:  [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uFmAR/2/)

I know you said you don't like empty divs but, you need to be able to play with z-indexing in order to achieve this affect so you'll need an absolutely positioned div somewhere as far as I know.

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. Could you illustrate on a jsfiddle how you would do the overlay? I don't like using empty `div`s.

Comment: Added a demo of this. However, I am not sure how you can achieve this effect without using an empty div.