# Using `.css` for pseudo-elements

Tags: jquery, css, pseudo-element

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Manipulating CSS :before and :after pseudo-elements using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/manipulating-css-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-using-jquery)

I would like to the jQuery equivalent this CSS code:

```
p:before {
   content: 'Intro!';
}
```

I've naively tried `$('p:before').css('content', 'Intro!');` but it doesn't work.

How can I do pseudo-element CSS modifications using jQuery?

Comment: That post doesn't really provide an answer...

Comment: @Randomblue: How is "You can't use jQuery to modify pseudo-elements" not an answer?

Comment: @Sotiris: I'm not interested in manipulating the CSS *element* itself, just changing a CSS *property*.

Comment: Are you sure this can't be stored as custom attributes?

Comment: @BoltClock: I was looking for a positive answer. Maybe there is a workaround using raw JavaScript, or a pluggin, or something else

Comment: @Randomblue: A negative answer is still an answer. In any case, sorry to disappoint.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't.

1) The selector, `p:before`, is not just a selector -- the psuedo element defines functionality that does not affect the actual selection. What is jQuery supposed to return, all `p` tags? That's all `$(...)` does -- it returns a bunch of elements that match your selector. jQuery (Sizzle/`querySelectorAll`) doesn't know how to fetch `:before`...

2) Psuedo-element/class behaviour is not available via JS APIs either.

The only way to do something like this, dynamically via JS, would be to create a `<style>` element, like so:

```
$('<style>p:before{content:"intro";}</style>').appendTo('head');
```

May I ask why you want to do this in the first place?

Comment: The reason I want this is to have an overlay on a specific element, with that specific element changing over time. Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7731523/doing-overlays-without-an-empty-div) question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$(document).append($("<style>p:before{ content: 'Intro!' } </style>"));
```

Comment: Yuck! No inline `style` please.

Comment: @Randomblue: inline stylesheet =/= inline style.